# Evaluation on the right side of an assignment

Tags: c, gcc, syntax

This `int c = (a==b)` is exactly what I'd like to say in my C program, compiling with GCC. I can do it, obviously (it works just fine), but I don't know whether it may cause undefined behavior. My program will not be compiled with some other compiler or in other architectures.  Is this legal ANSI C? Thanks.

Comment: What's undefined about it? o_O

Comment: What compiler doesn't accept it ?

Comment: So, you mean the answer is "yes, it is legal"? Why would you answer a question with another question?

Answer (score 4):

It's completely legal. if `a` is equal to `b`, then `c` will be 1. else, it will be 0.

Comment: If `a` is equal to `b`, then `c` could be anything non-zero, right?

Comment: @Teh: No it must be 1. (C99 §6.5.9/3 says so.)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that it must be 1. (any non-zero number means true, but comparing operators return only 0 or 1) Edit: I wrote this before seeing KennyTM's comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
int c = (a == b);
```

this is perfectly legal. Initialization is part of the C standard (C99 §6.7.8), the right hand side can just be any *assignment-expression*, including `a == b` (of course, assuming `a` and `b` are defined and have comparable type).

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid if `c` is declared at block scope.

When declared at file scope it is not valid because the initializer has to be a constant expression.

`a == b` is an expression and in that sense is not different that another expression like `a + b` or `a & b`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what the types of `a` and `b` are. If they are types that support equality check, then yes, it's perfectly legal.